# Default profile photo

Tags: flutter, dart, amazon-s3, aws-amplify, flutter-test

I have an app and when users sign up, the profile photo `URL` is required though I have noticed not everybody may want to add a profile photo at sign up. So I want that when a user doesn't add a profile photo then a default profile photo `URL` be added instead and saved to the `Database`. Here is the function that return the `URL`:

```
// add_a_file_to_aws_s3
  Future<GetUrlResult> uploadImage(File? file, String? key) async {
    try {
      await Amplify.Storage.uploadFile(
        local: file!,
        key: key!,
        onProgress: (progress) {
          // ignore: avoid_print
          print('Fraction completed: ${progress.getFractionCompleted()}');
        },
      );
      GetUrlResult urlResult = await Amplify.Storage.getUrl(key: key);
      return urlResult;
    } on StorageException {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

and here is the code to add user information to the `Database` after signing up:

```
final result = await Amplify.Auth.signUp(
        username: username.text.trim(),
        password: password.text.trim(),
        options: CognitoSignUpOptions(userAttributes: userAttributes),
      );

      GetUrlResult urlResult = await uploadImage(file, 'Profile Photos');

      await userController.addUserData(
        username.text,
        password.text,
        emailAddress.text,
        urlResult.toString(),
        int.parse('zero'),
        int.parse('zero'),
        birthday.text,
        gender.text,
        location.text,
        phoneNumber.text,
      );
      setState(() {
        isSignUpComplete = result.isSignUpComplete;
      });
```

I created the `userController();` file and that's where I created the function `addUserData`. Right Now I need help adding the default profile photo `URL` to the `Database` when user doesn't add any. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just do :

```
Future<GetUrlResult> uploadImage(File? file, String? key) async {
    try {
      await Amplify.Storage.uploadFile(
        local: file!,
        key: key!,
        onProgress: (progress) {
          // ignore: avoid_print
          print('Fraction completed: ${progress.getFractionCompleted()}');
        },
      );
      GetUrlResult urlResult = await Amplify.Storage.getUrl(key: key);
      if(urlResult.isEmpty){ //just add this
        default_url = 'your_photo_url';
        return default_url;
      } else {
      return urlResult;
      }
    } on StorageException {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks man. Tried that though differently and got stuck but now lemme do that and again thanks

Comment: sure ask me if any problem occurs